# Can I travel to other EU countries with Spain multi entry visa?

Tags: visas, indian-citizens, schengen-visas, spain

I am a citizen of India, have visa for Spain with Multiple number of entries valid for 160days.
Can I travel to other EU countries like France, Germany, Netherlands etc with the same visa ?

Comment: Is your visa of type C or D?

Comment: @HenningMakholm Hmm, how is that relevant? Both C and D visas have Schengen-wide coverage by default

Comment: @Coke: It's mostly relevant because the interpretation of the "valid for" field is different in the two cases, and a targeted explanation of that would be natural as part of an answer.

Comment: @HenningMakholm it's type D visa

Comment: @Deeksha: In that case, beware that type D visas only have a single country name in the "valid for" field (because that's the only place they allow a _long stay_ -- but **nevertheless** they are also good for _short_ visits to all the other Schengen countries.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do so only if you have a Schengen visa as opposed to individual country visa or LTV.
Any eventual restrictions will be specifically stated on your visa ( for example excluded countries or included countries ) so read carefully and if none exists than you are good to go.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you hold an LTV visa, you can travel to other Schengen countries, as well as to Croatia, Romania, Bulgaria and Cyprus.